# Exponentially delay repeat requests to the same file in php

Tags: php, security, download, bots, copy-protection

I'm looking to prevent robots crawling our site and downloading the thousands of images hosted there.

I read this lately https://github.com/remy/password-policy about best practices for password policy. One of the ideas was to **delay repeat requests exponentially** there by not limiting humans but punishing bots.

Would this be possible in php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to rewrite the relevant URLs to a PHP script, that implements the download. This would

- keep a list of source addresses (e.g. in memcached) with their last timestamp and penalty time
- double or zero the penalty time according to the timestamp,
- write the record back
- and finally sleep and do the download.